# Convert spark dataframe to parquet

Tags: pyspark, parquet

I have a spark dataframe containing 40 Mio rows including 4 columns with dates.

Looking into the schema they are set correctly set as date columns, means containing no strings.

Nevertheless, writing this dataframe to .parquet

```
table.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("name").parquet(output + table_name + ".parquet")
```

always ends up in following error:

```
    return d.toordinal() - self.EPOCH_ORDINAL
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toordinal'
```

So the write process wants to convert any of the string fields to date, for whatever reason.

Looking into the traceback of the error gives no hint on which field might cause this behaviour.

Is there a way to find out which field/row it is? And it is not affecting all rows. Runnig this with a smaller set of records works fine.

```
/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    376         """
    377         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 378             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    379         else:
    380             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o486.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 65.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.0 in stage 65.0 (TID 120, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 345, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 141, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 334, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 83, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: toInternal(f(*a))
  File "/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 174, in toInternal
    return d.toordinal() - self.EPOCH_ORDINAL
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage8.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:148)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3383)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2758)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 345, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 141, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 334, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 83, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: toInternal(f(*a))
  File "/opt/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 174, in toInternal
    return d.toordinal() - self.EPOCH_ORDINAL
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage8.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:148)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Try removing one column at a time to see which column(s) is causing the error.
When you know which column(s) is causing the problem you can try to identify which entry is causing the problem.

Comment: Finally i had to do it this way, lacking programmatic alternatives. Was caused by a value slipping through conversion to datetime and therefore remained a string. Thanks.

Comment: glad it helped. Please give my comment a "thumbs up" if you found it useful ^^